# Finding first available ID from an array

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array like this:

```
Array => (
  [0] => 1,
  [1] => 2,
  [2] => 3,
  [3] => 5,
  [4] => 6
)
```

What is the easiest way to find the first 'available' ID in that array – that is, the first value in the sequence `[1,2,3...n]` that does not exist in the array? In this case, the correct answer would be `4`.

I can do this using some while loops or sorts with temp variables but that's a bit messy, so I'm interested to see if anyone can come up with a 'clever' solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My PHP skills are a bit rusty, but couldn't you use [`range`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [`array_diff`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$missing = array_diff(range(1, end($myArray)+ 1), $myArray);
echo $missing[0];
```

Updated with Tatu Ulmanen's corrections (i told ya my PHP was rusty ;-))

Comment: +1 That's the kind of answer I originally wanted to give, didn't know about `range` though and creating the sequence array oneself would indeed be messy. However, you probably have to use `array_keys($myArray)` as the first arguement and take into account the possibility that there is no hole in the array.

Comment: This is just the kind of solution I'm looking for. This should work with one correction: `end($myArray)` instead of `count($myArray)`, as the count might be less than the largest value in the array.

Comment: Whoops, forget about the `array_keys()`. I think I misread the question into something else.

Comment: @Andy, this actually needed some modifications to get it working; first of all, the "full" array has to be first, and the range should extend to `end($myArray) + 1` to allow it to return the next ID if there are no holes in `$myArray`. So the correct version would look like this: `array_diff(range(1, end($myArray)+ 1), $myArray);`

Comment: @Tatu: Glad you got it working in the end.  I didn't realize the range would have to go in as the first parameter.  I've updated the post again :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't really think up anything except sorting the array and going through it, looking for holes.

Maybe something like:

```
sort($array);
$next_available = array_shift($array);
foreach($array as $_k) {
    ++$next_available;
    if($_k > $next_available) {
        break;
    }
}
echo "Next available index: {$next_available}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is less messy than some loop, but here goes my contrived example:

```
sort( $array );
$range = range( reset( $array ), end( $array ) );
$diff = array_diff( $range, $array );
$result = null != ( $result = array_shift( $diff ) ) ? $result : end( $array ) + 1;
```

Comment: Can't believe you beat me by 31 seconds, I knew I shouldn't have bothered fetching the links lol.

Comment: Haha, I know the feeling but all too well. ;-) Yours is a bit cleaner though. Although stricts standards don't allow you to pass arguments to `array_diff` like that.

Comment: as I said in my answer, my PHP skills are a bit rusty so I don't do much with strict standards.  I write some PHP maybe once every couple of months or so :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of magic, but does the trick:

```
$values = array_values($id_array);
$values[] = max($values) + 1;
$combined = array_values(array_flip($values) + array_keys($values));
$missing = isset($combined[count($values) + 1])
    ? $combined[count($values) + 1]
    : end($values);
```

The advantage of this is that it's considerably fast. The problem with using `range()` would be that single large key in a small array would make `array_diff()` very slow. In addition, this will return the next key if there are no gaps in the IDs (or you could change final `end($values)` to `false`, if that's what you would prefer).

Despite the cleverness, it's still slower than simply iterating through the array. But `array_diff()` (even without `range()`) would be much, much slower.

Answer (score 0):

if your array use only numeric key and without hole, you can do `$next_id = count($your_array)`

if there is holes, ou can try

```
$keys = array_keys($your_array);
rsort($keys);
$next_id = empty($keys)?0:($keys[0]+1);
```

Comment: rsort returns a bool, doesn't it?