# Get next available ID from array of names

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have 3 strings, each contained within an array.

`string[] folderArray = {"1 - Name", "4 - Another name", "3 - Another name"}`

I need to get the next available ID (folder number) available.

For the example, the ID required would be 2 because it would see that the "2" ID is missing from the array.

A PHP duplicate of this question can be found at [Finding first available ID from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424211/finding-first-available-id-from-an-array)

Comment: What part of this task do you not know how to do? parsing out the int from the string? looping over the array? Figuring out the first available ID? You need to narrow your question down.

Comment: I think this question is a typical XY-Problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  WHAT are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain & dognose I'm trying to get the "2" ID from it seeing as it's the next numerical ID that isn't taken by a string yet.

Comment: Yes, we know that, you still have not told us "What part of this task do you not know how to do? parsing out the int from the string? looping over the array? Figuring out the first available ID? "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    string[] folderArray = { "1 - Name", "4 - Another name", "3 - Another name" };
    var listId = new List<int>();
    foreach (var item in folderArray)
    {
       var tempId = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(item.Split('-')[0].Trim(), out tempId))
           listId.Add(tempId);
    }




   listId.Sort();
   for (var i=1 ;i<listId.Count ;i++)
   {
      if(listId[i]-listId[i-1]>1)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(listId[i-1]+1);
          break;
        }
   }
```

Comment: i tested it in a console application

Comment: I tested this but it gave the missing number twice, ie. it printed "2" then it looped again printing another two, then dies. I don't fully understand this code so I can't exactly fix it myself, unfortunately

Comment: @Scarsz the first loop is to get the IdList.
After sorting a second loop will stop when it finds your ID ,shows it and break.

Comment: Oh. Gee. Shows how much of a C# noob I am. This does the job, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

if you use the SortedList class, you will fix the problem...Look this code

```
SortedList<int, string> lista = new SortedList<int, string>();
lista.Add(4, "Name");
lista.Add(1, "Name");
lista.Add(3, "Name");
lista.Add(7, "Name");
int nextID = 1;
foreach (var item in lista.Keys)
{
   if (nextID != item) break;
   else nextID++;
}
Console.WriteLine(nextID);
```

The SortedList class recieve a TKey parameter, and a TValue parameter. She sort the elements by the TKey parameter. You only have to add the elements in the list, and she'll do the works for you...Then, search the next Id no exist in the list. The lista.Keys returns an IEnumerable with all the keys added, in decrease order...

Answer (score 1):

Think about the following points:

- Don't use an array of strings, use a sorted collection (e.g. `SortedList<int, String>`) with a correct `IComparer<int>` (try `Comparer<int>.Default`)
- Then iterate in order and find the first gap where gap means: `list.ContainsKey(n) == true && list.ContainsKey(n + 1) == false` - then the next ID is `n + 1`
- For performance enhancements, you could memorize the last ID you gave to a caller (or the last folder that was deleted if that is supported as well) and start searching from there for the next request for an ID

I wanted to post this as  a comment but it doesn't work with the formatting :-/.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it like this, but if you would like the same as in the PHP solution you linked:

```
var missing = Enumerable.Range(1, folderArray.Length).Except(folderArray.Select(f => int.Parse(f.Split('-').First()))).First();
```

Note: This has the assumption that the items in the folderArray are always in the form

- "[number] - [some string]"

no empty string, no nulls, etc.

Comment: I didn't know I would be getting a answer specific to the rest of the string other than the ID, the situation is truly that the string would be "ID - Name of something - Name of folder contents" An example would be "1 - Game - Some Game Files". Would this code have to be changed to match that?

Comment: No, but still, this is for replicating the answer you quoted in your question, I wouldn't use it in production code.